# What is the difference between Campaign and Campaign Members?

Tags: campaign, campaign-member

What is the difference between Campaign and Campaign Members?

Answer (score 4):

From the [help](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=campaigns_def.htm)

> A campaign is an outbound marketing project that you want to plan,
>   manage, and track within Salesforce. It can be a direct mail program,
>   seminar, print advertisement, email, or other type of marketing
>   initiative. You can organize campaigns into hierarchies for easy
>   analysis of related marketing tactics.

Campaign members are the contacts and leads in your CRM that you included in the campaign and are trying to market to.  If it's a direct mail campaign, its the people you sent the mailing to.  If it's a seminar, it's the people that you invited.  If it's an email campaign, it's the people you sent the email to.  You can then track their activity, such as if they clicked on a link in the email, if they rsvp'ed for the seminar, and if they actually showed up, etc.

In Salesforce, when you visit a campaign record, the campaign members are a related list.

Answer (score 3):

A campaign is an outbound marketing project that you want to plan, manage, and track within Salesforce. It can be a direct mail program, seminar, print advertisement, email, or other type of marketing initiative. You can organize campaigns into hierarchies for easy analysis of related marketing tactics.
([Campaign help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=campaigns_def.htm)

A campaign member is a person (lead, contact, or person account records) who you are trying to reach with a given campaign.